# Android AsyncTask pass variable value

Tags: android

How do I pass value on doInBackground so It can use it. When I type the String directly inside doInBackgroud it works. But I have three type "Professional", "General", "Special" I don't want to create 3 asyncTask. In my research i found that I need to create contructor but im don't get It.

```
    String type = "professional"; 


    new loadQuestioners().execute(type);

    public class loadQuestioners extends AsyncTask <String, Integer, JSONArray> {

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        //is the arg0 is the type i passed?

        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify the code as follows,

```
public class loadQuestioners extends AsyncTask <String, Integer, JSONArray> {

@Override
protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... arg0) {

    //is the arg0 is the type i passed?
    String yourType=arg0[0];


    return null;
}
```

"yourType" contains the type you passed while creating asyncTask

Comment: So if I have a new loadQuestioners().execute(type, type2, type3);   String yourType = arg[0];                                              String yourType2 = arg[1]; and so on? Nc thx

Comment: Then you can access them using the code, for(String type: arg0 ){
    //do something with type passed
   }

Comment: w8 I try this in my project

Answer (score 1):

I can see two ways of going about this:
1st:

```
new loadQuestioners().execute("professional");

public class loadQuestioners extends AsyncTask <String, Integer, JSONArray> 
{
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... arg) 
    {
        String word = arg[0];
        return null;
    }
}
```

And 2nd: create a constructor and pass the argument:

```
new loadQuestioners("professional").execute();

public class loadQuestioners extends AsyncTask <String, Integer, JSONArray> 
{
    private String word;

    public loadQuestioners(String word)
    {
         this.word = word;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... arg0) 
    {
        //use word
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, I'm posting from my phone.

Comment: No problem but making contructor inside Asynctask make me confuse because without contructor It seems it will work

Comment: yes, both ways are correct and work, it's just a matter a preference. Personally I like the 2nd method more because I find it more readable than the 1st where you have to use the array index to access the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

`String... args` means that it can take as paramrters:

- a single String object OR
- an array of Strings

So in your case pass an array of Strings to your async task's  execute method and doInBackground will get them just fine. Inside doInBackground use the `arg0` parameter as a String array and you should be good.